# Update on geoserver settings rest call for contact information doesn't work

Tags: geoserver

When I try to update the contact information for geoserver global settings using https://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/rest/settings doesn't work. When I try to update below info using the above call

```
                   <global>
                        <settings>
                            <contact>
                                <address>test</address>
                                <addressCity>Hyderabad</addressCity>
                                <addressCountry>India</addressCountry>
                            </contact>
                        </settings>
                    </global>
```

It resets all the details from contact info and put only the above three fields. Is there any attribute or a way to make it work as expected. My requirement is to update only the fields sent through the request and keeping the remaining fields unchanged.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @iant: I have one more question. can you please see the following link and help.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990413/geoserver-elasticsearch-layer-is-not-created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `GET` all the contact info as an XML or JSON file and then make the changes you need and then `POST` the changed file back to GeoServer.

Comment: Thanks @iant, thought we had any attribute to send with the call to make this work.